# PLSQL Get All table Data

Tags: oracle, plsql, powerbi

I have a function in PLSQL and trying to call it from PowerBI which I finally got it to work.

Currently to return a tables columns, I need to manually specify the types. Is there a way to simply edit this code to return all columns of any given table?

Meaning that given this script, I only need to change the name of the table in the script and it should give me all the data.

I have to use PLSQL for this as there are some Auth protection to query tables which I cant simply query from PowerBI.

```
Drop Type VW_PEOPLE_TABLE;
Drop Type VW_PEOPLE_TYPE;
Drop Function TESTPOWERBI;
Drop Public Synonym PBI;

CREATE TYPE VW_PEOPLE_TYPE AS Object
{
     Name VarChar2(70).
     ALIAS VarChar2(90)
};
/
Create Type VW_PEOPLE_TABLE as TABLE OF VW_PEOPLE_TYPE;
/
Grant execute on VW_PEOPLE_TABLE TO public;

Create Function TESTPOWERBI
     Return VW_PEOPLE_TABLE Pipelined AUTHID current_user AS VWT VW_PEOPLE_TABLE;
     Pragma AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
Begin
    Select VW_PEOPLE_TYPE(NAME,ALIAS) 
    Bulk COLLECT INTO VWT 
    FROM mytable;

    FOR I IN 1 .. VWT.count 
    LOOP
        PIPE ROW(VW_PEOPLE_TYPE(VWT(I).NAME, VWT(I).ALIAS));
    END LOOP;
END TESTPOWERBI;
/
create public synonym PBI for TESTPOWERBI;
Grant Execute on PBI to public;
```

Comment: Not that clear to me. Say you have a function that handles a parameter for the table name; how do you know the columns to get?

Comment: Short answer, No. We need to specify the RETURN type with a strong data type. However, it's not clear why you think you need to use a pipelined function to expose data to Power BI. Probably there's a better way of doing whatever it is you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** : as per this [**powerBI**](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-call-execute-a-oracle-stored-procedure-from-powerbi/td-p/14127/page/2) community post :

You should be able to achieve it using a procedure like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_query_result (
    p_tab_name VARCHAR2,
    p_rc OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS
BEGIN
    OPEN p_rc FOR 'select * FROM '
                || p_tab_name;
 END;
/
```

In Oracle environment, If you are using Oracle 12c and above, you may use `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT` with a dynamic `REFCURSOR`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_query_result (
    p_tab_name VARCHAR2
) AS
    rc   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN rc FOR 'select * FROM '
                || p_tab_name;


    dbms_sql.return_result(rc);
END;
/
```

Get the query result for any table using

```
EXEC get_query_result('EMPLOYEES');
```

Comment: You should enquote the table name (using dbms_assert.enquote_name for example) to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: Thanks this works in sqlplus. But PowerBI only accepts SQL statements and does not recognize EXEC get_query_result('EMPLOYEES');

Comment: @RStyle - a quick Google for Power BI and Oracle ref cursor turned up [this forum thread](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-call-execute-a-oracle-stored-procedure-from-powerbi/td-p/14127/page/2) showing how to plug ref cursors into Power BI. So it can be done.

Comment: @APC thanks! I tried using call get_query_result('...') , PowerBI says implicit result cannot be returned through this statement line 7

Comment: @RStyle : Maybe you can avoid `dbms_sql.return_result(rc) ` and simply fetch from the cursor as out parameter in your PowerBI?

Comment: @Rstyle : Check out the link, there's a code snippet  explainung how to fetch  from a procedure in powerBI